# Работа с tableLayout в Android

Tags: android-textview, android, java, tableview

Пишу приложение с таблицами, которые создаются программно, в коде классов (а не в xml).

Требуется вставить объект ImageView в начале каждой строки (строки текстовые).
Если вставлять таким образом:

```
tableRow.addView(imageView);
tableRow.addView(textView);
tableRow.addView(textView);
```

то приложение при запуске выдаёт ошибку. Как быть? Отдельной строкой эта же картинка вставляется, а в состав строки входить не хочет.

Comment: Покажите стектрейс исключения.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сделать так
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this); // и не забудьте добавить все нужные параметры
    tableRow.addView(ll);
    ll.addView(imageView);
    ll.addView(textView);

Comment: К сожалению, как и ранее, приложение выдаёт ошибку при запуске.
При чём, для начала добавил одну лишь картинку в LinearLayout.